# When an Adobe AIR app requests a resource from the server what shows as user agent?

Tags: apache, actionscript-3, flash, air

When a browser like Chrome makes a request for a web page or image like a gravatar icon the server receives the userAgent information like so:

```
"Chrome/2.0 AppleWebKit/400.1.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
```

But if an Adobe AIR app makes a request for an image in the Image component what does the server receive? Is the same as a URLRequest?

```
"Chrome/2.0 AppleWebKit/400.1.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/3.0"
```

**Background**:
My AIR app shows Gravatar icon for the user and recently it stopped working. I'm wondering if it's gravatar is denying calls from user agents it doesn't recognize.

I've tried changing the userAgent to test the theory and it's throwing an error:

```
// 1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method userAgent through a reference with static type Class.
URLRequestDefaults.userAgent("chrome");
```

**Update:**
It looks like I need to set the user agent as a property and not a method. Was referring to this forum [post](https://forums.adobe.com/message/955554#955554). So I can change that might fix the gravatar issue but not answer how Adobe AIR apps appear to the server.

Answer (score 0):

i hope [this result's](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/tools/user-agent-parser/browse/view/adobe-air--193) comes useful

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) AdobeAIR/3.1

[image]

also i cant realize that what's difference between requesting for an Image and URLRequest, they are same.